# Meetup API, how to get gender and birthday

Tags: date, meetup

According to the the help docs "gender" is an "optional fields parameter", but I can't get it when I use

```
request = requests.get("http://api.meetup.com/2/members?fields=birthday",params=params)
```

Is it possible for me to get the gender and birthday of members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get the gender and birthday of the currently-authenticated member. Meetup does not currently share this information with other members.